# Ansible module failing with 'no route to host'

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am running a playbook against a RHEL 7.4 image which sits behind a proxy.  SELINUX and the firewall have been disabled.  I am using Ansible 2.5.3

Here is the task

```
- name: Add Docker repository.
get_url:
  url: "{{ docker_yum_repo_url }}"
  dest: '/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-{{ docker_edition }}.repo'
  owner: root
  group: root
  mode: 0644
  use_proxy: yes
```

And the error

```
fatal: [10.40.12.136]: FAILED! => changed=false 
invocation:

module_args:

  attributes: null

  backup: null

  checksum: ''

  client_cert: null

  client_key: null

  content: null

  delimiter: null

  dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

  directory_mode: null

  follow: false

  force: false

  force_basic_auth: false

  group: root

  headers: null

  http_agent: ansible-httpget

  mode: 420

  owner: root

  regexp: null

  remote_src: null

  selevel: null

  serole: null

  setype: null

  seuser: null

  sha256sum: ''

  src: null

  timeout: 10

  tmp_dest: null

  unsafe_writes: null

  url: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

  url_password: null

  url_username: null

  use_proxy: true

  validate_certs: true

 msg: 'Failed to connect to download.docker.com at port 443: [Errno 113] No route to host'
```

If I ssh into the server I can wget or curl the file with no issue at all and as you can see the module is been configured to use my proxy.

UPDATE: It does appear to be trying to use my proxy

```
<10.47.69.136> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'http_proxy=http://192.168.1.240:8080 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1527849642.94-177395007646298/get_url.py && sleep 0'
```

thanks.

Comment: "No route to host" means you have a network configuration problem.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but as stated if I ssh into the device with the same credentials I can reach the exact same target. DNS resolves, and I can pull down the file via my proxy. So the question stands, why does the Ansible python module fail

Comment: It looks like it is not using a proxy. Have you checked your environment variables on the host?

Comment: I've updated my original question to show the output where it seems to be using the proxy

Answer (score 0):

Try set your proxy in that specific task like this:

```
- name: Add Docker repository.
  get_url:
    url: "{{ docker_yum_repo_url }}"
    dest: '/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-{{ docker_edition }}.repo'
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    use_proxy: yes
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://yourproxy:3128
```

but if you also need use proxy on other tasks, set the environment var on your playbook, not just in that task...

```
---
- hosts: all
  environment:
    http_proxy: [...]
  tasks:
    - name: Add docker repo
      [...]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I a have already set the proxy at the top of the play like you showed above. Sort my original question didn't show that. I've updated my question to show that it does seem to be trying to use the proxy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ansible 2.4.6, following fix works for me:

```
- name: Add Docker repository.
  get_url:
    url: "{{ docker_yum_repo_url }}"
    dest: '/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-{{ docker_edition }}.repo'
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    use_proxy: yes
    validate_certs: no
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32750#issuecomment-423989886), it works with `validate_certs: no` ans worked for me.